# JQUERY Effect highlight, control the Start & End colors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, highlight, jquery-effects

I have the following:

```
$(".notifycell_email_dailydigest").effect('highlight');
```

The element I want to highlight is over a gray background. Problem is the highlight goes from Yellow to white, and has this ugly slow pause at the end on the white which makes the animation look horrible.

How can I modify the highlighy to start with the yellow but end on the gray so it matches the background?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the highlight effect only checks for the background-color of the element getting hightlighted and doesn't check if any of its parents have a background-color if it doesn't.  If you give it the gray background-color directly with css it should fade to that color.

http://jsfiddle.net/eaQf6/